# Classification of entire solutions to hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

**Question/Motivation**

I am trying to classify all of the entire (i.e. holomorphic) solutions to a simple-looking ODE of the form

$$z\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2} + (az+b)\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+(cz+d)f=0.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$

*without directly solving the recursion* (i.e. by applying transformations to simplify the ODE into a hypergeometric ODE, and then taking the standard holomorphic solutions). What indicates that this may be a difficult task is the limiting case $a=d=0$:

$$z\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2} + b\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+czf=0.$$
$$$$

**Mathematica/Wikipedia gets stuck:**

In this limiting case, the [standard derivation in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Other_equations), in addition to *Mathematica*'s DSolve[], both seem to miss a holomorphic solution. In particular, the Wikipedia derivation and Mathematica both spit out a set of solutions of the form
\begin{align*}
f_1&=\,_0F_1(b;-cz^2/4)\\
f_2&=(-cz^2/4)^{1-b}\,_0F_1(2-b;-cz^2/4)\\
\end{align*}
$f_2$ is not entire, so I usually just discard this solution, as I am looking to find only entire functions. What's disturbing about this, however, is that I have found a *third* linearly independent solution, which happens to be entire, and which is completely missed by *Mathematica*, and all of the references I find online:
\begin{align*}
f_3&:=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(b)_m}\frac{(-cz^2/2)^m}{(2m)!!}
\end{align*}
Here, $(b)_k:=\Gamma(b+k)/\Gamma(b)$ is the Pochammer symbol. I am deeply troubled by the sight of a solution slipping past my computer algebra program: what is happening here? Is the theory behind these equations incomplete, or is there a deep explanation behind the existence of this extra solution? Why is Mathematica unable to find this holomorphic solution?

Comment: It is a shame this question is not receiving much attention. I think it is interesting. BTW: The Wikipedia link is broken.

Comment: a) $f_3=f_1$ if you convert the double factorials into simple factorials.  b)$f_1$ and $f_2$ are only ok if $b$ is not an integer.  c) The hypergeometric equation has three singular points, yours has only two, so it might be reduced to a confluent hypergeometric equation only (but probably not always).

Comment: I think that resolves it. If you submit an answer then I will approve it, thanks!